# Check if the sub-query includes all of the stated values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to find movie_ids for movies that both johnny Depp and Helena Bonham Carted played in. I'm using SQLite3 as software and the famous IMDB dataset.

- The result I got: ids for movies that either of them played
- The Desired result: ids for movies that both of them played in

  ```
   select movie_id from stars where person_id in
   (select id from people where name in 
   ("Johnny Depp", "Helena Bonham Carter"))
  ```

  );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.movie_id
FROM stars s
INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = s.person_id
WHERE p.name in ('Johnny Depp', 'Helena Bonham Carter')
GROUP BY s.movie_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) = 2
```

Comment: I think you want: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) = 2`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If the same actor could be listed with the same movie more than once, then yes. I've not played with this data set, but intuition is that shouldn't happen... though I suppose sometimes an actor gets more than one credit (ie: Eddie Murphy/Nutty Professor), so I'll make the change.